# OPENGL get Height from terrain object

Tags: opengl

I have loaded a terrain object (basically a mountain) and I am using particles to create a snowfall effect. I would like whenever a particle hits the terrain to stop moving. I was thinking to get the x,z coordinates of the particle and check if for the same coordinates the terrain has a bigger or equal y to the particle (which means that the particle "hit" the terrain). My problem is that I dont know how to get the coordinates of a particular spot of the terrain.

Comment: Render your mountains with  orto-projection matrix with top view, and pass z coordinate to frag color. So you will get the height map.

Comment: Ray tracing is a little bit more complicated to implement.You need to render and read back just once, then use height map to check if particle fell down.

Comment: How is your terrain represented? Height map? Mesh? Voxels?